# keras-gym library has assertion issue

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have posted already two question about frameworks for reinforcement learning and did not get an answer. This indicates two things:

1. either on this website there  are few people who knows  materials in reinforcement learning.
2. documentation and  tutorials for RL is outdated, one example is this web site: [keras-gym](https://keras-gym.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Here is the code:

```
import gym
import keras_gym as km
from tensorflow import keras

# the cart-pole MDP
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
class Linear(km.FunctionApproximator):
    """ linear function approximator """
    def body(self, SA,variable_scope):
        # body is trivial, only flatten and then pass to head (one dense layer)
        return keras.layers.Flatten()(SA)
# value function and its derived policy
func = Linear(env, lr=0.001)
q = km.QTypeI(func, update_strategy='sarsa',gamma=0.9,)
policy = km.EpsilonGreedy(q,epsilon=0.1)
# static parameters
num_episodes = 200
num_steps = env.spec.max_episode_steps
# used for early stopping
num_consecutive_successes = 0
# train
for ep in range(num_episodes):
    s = env.reset()
    policy.epsilon = 0.1 if ep < 10 else 0.01
    for t in range(num_steps):
        a = policy.greedy(s)
        s_next, r, done, info = env.step(a)
        q.update(s, a, r, done)
        if done:
            if t == num_steps - 1:
                num_consecutive_successes += 1
                print("num_consecutive_successes: {}"
                      .format(num_consecutive_successes))
            else:
                num_consecutive_successes = 0
                print("failed after {} steps".format(t))
            break

        s = s_next
    if num_consecutive_successes == 10:
        break
# run env one more time to render
km.render_episode(env, policy, step_delay_ms=25)
```

which shows following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\keras_AI_Projects\episode_cartpole.py", line 26, in <module>
    a = policy.greedy(s)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\keras_AI_Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras_gym\policies\value_based.py", line 66, in greedy
    Q = self.q_function(s)  # shape: [num_actions]
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\keras_AI_Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras_gym\function_approximators\base.py", line 385, in __call__
    assert self.env.observation_space.contains(s)
AssertionError
```